# Backbone.js - get view, model or collection property in ajax 'beforeSend'

Tags: node.js, backbone.js, backbone-views, backbone.js-collections, backbone-model

I am using Backbone.js in my node app. I am calling various ajax call from views, models and colllection. I have created my custom property e.g. "myName" in every view, model and collection and assigned with unique name for each. Now I want this "myName" property in ajax "beforeSend", So I should know from which view or model, this ajax is called. Is there any option to do this?

Comment: Do you have custom `$.ajax` calls or all interaction with the server done using `backbone.model` and `backbone.collection`'s?

Comment: @VahanVardanyan, I have made $.ajaxSetup(), and trashing all ajax call in "beforeSend". In this method, I want from which model or collection, this ajax is called?

Comment: I have added an answer.

Answer (score 1):

`beforeSend` callback of [$.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) receives 2 arguments:

> beforeSend
>
> Type: Function( jqXHR jqXHR, PlainObject settings )

As you can see 2nd argument is `settings` which receives all options passed to `fetch` method of 'Backbone.Collection' or `Backbone.Model`:

**Example:**

Your ajax setup:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
       beforeSend: function (xhr, options) {
           console.log(options.testVar); // Will be "Hello" when collection fetched
       }
});
```

Place when you doing fetch() or somehow interacting with server:

```
yourCustomCollectionOrModel.fetch({testVar: "Hello"}).done(function(){
    // bla bla        
})
```

So whenever `yourCustomCollectionOrModel` has fetched `testVar` will be passed to the `beforeSend`'s `options` argument.

**Note:** Avoid globals if you can solve the issue in more preferred way.

---

You can go event better if you don't want to repeat the same any time you fetching collection or model.

Just rewrite the `fetch()` method, and add collection/model specific flag to the options.

**Example**

```
var TestCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    url: 'your/api/path', 
    fetch: function (options) {
        options = options || {};
        options.testVar = 'Hello';
        return this.constructor.__super__.fetch.call(this, options);
    }
});
```

**Update:**

Another and maybe the shortest way to achieve the same behavior, is to wrap `Backbone.sync` like this:

```
  var oldSync = Backbone.sync;
  Backbone.sync = function(method, model, options) {
    options = options || {};
    options.modelContext = model;
    return oldSync.call(Backbone, method, model, options);
  }
```

In this way you don't need to rewrite fetch, or manually pass options to `fetch()` method.

And the in beforeSend callback of $.ajax:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
       beforeSend: function (xhr, options) {
           console.log(options.modelContext); // this will be the model's or collection's instance
       }
});
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: thanks @vahan-vardanyan, I am doing more or less same thing as you mentioned. As per your example, I have to set options in fetch, which is received in settings in "beforeSend". but Here I want "yourCustomCollectionOrModel" or atleast yourCustomCollectionOrModel.myName property without passing it in option. Is there any way?

Comment: You need to somehow access the scope of collection or model, so you need some reference to it. `beforeSend`'s arguments doesn't hold such kind of information. Actual $.ajax call done in the `Backbone.sync`, so you can rewrite it to pass collection/model to the $.ajax as option by default. But I guess it's not a good idea

Comment: thanks @vahan-vardanyan for yr reply, but sorry I couldn't understand what you explain due to my bed English. Can you please give any example for the same?

Comment: Look at the [definition](http://backbonejs.org/docs/backbone.html#section-141) of `Backbone.sync` . You somehow need to reference collection/model from `beforeSend`, and the best way is `options`.

Comment: @ManishSapkal I added update to the question. I assume this is the best way for you.

Answer (score 0):

```
// for example
$.ajaxSetup({
       beforeSend: function (xhr) {
           xhr.setRequestHeader('viewName', yourGlobalVariable /* or session storage */);
       }
});
```

before each ajax call (or model/collection fetch, save etc) store in `yourGlobalVariable` name of your view.